# Live playercount in Photon rooms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have a project where we use photon to make rooms for people to join.

I got it working to show the playercount, but the thing is it doesnt update the playercount live.
Is it possible to make the room show a live playercount in the room browser. Cause at the moment it only updates it when you disconnect and reconnect to the network. I've tried some work arounds but nothing seems to work.[image: This is how it currently looks. It only updates upon reconnecting to the server.]

^^This is how it currently looks. It only updates upon reconnecting to the server.^^

```
 public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
    foreach (RoomInfo info in roomList)
    {
        //Removed from rooms list
        if (info.RemovedFromList)
        {
            int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
            if(index != -1)
            {
                Destroy(_listings[index].gameObject);
                _listings.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
        //Added to rooms list
        else
        {
            int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                RoomListing listing = Instantiate(_roomListing, _content);
                if (listing != null)
                {
                    listing.SetRoomInfo(info);
                    _listings.Add(listing);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Modify listing here

            }
        }
    }
}
```

^^This is how our code looks like when a room gets created/removed.^^

```
public class RoomListing : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextMeshProUGUI _text;

    public RoomInfo RoomInfo { get; private set; }

    public void SetRoomInfo(RoomInfo roomInfo)
    {
        RoomInfo = roomInfo;
        _text.text = roomInfo.PlayerCount + "/" +roomInfo.MaxPlayers + "," + roomInfo.Name;
    }

    public void OnClick_Button()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(RoomInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

^^This is the code for adding the information of the room (such as the name, max players and in this case also the playercount.)

Does anybody know what we could do to make the playercount update live? We tried numerous things, with no succes sadly.

Comment: [`OnRoomListUpdate`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/interface_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_i_lobby_callbacks.html#a2b8d474598fdb36b849aa6ea75903cfc) is only called if the room list itself changes -> you connect or rooms get added, removed. The API leaves it quite unclear if it will also be called when properties of a room have changed

Comment: Have you tried to put a debug log where you have `//Modify listing here` ? Maybe it already is being called you just ignore the case currently

Comment: I cant check and confirm this currently but isnt there a real time counter in the demo scene?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code it's simply adding

```
_roomListing.SetRoomInfo(_listings[index].RoomInfo);
```

where `//Modify listing here` is.
this constantly updates the relevant room's info when its info changes.
In your relevant prefab for the listing just have a section in `SetRoomInfo(...)` where you add a line such as  `playerCountText.text = roomInfo.PlayerCount + "/"+roomInfo.MaxPlayers;` to update the relevant prefab component for playercount.